# useState array destructuring react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I always see this type of code:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
```

since `value` can be changed using `setValue`, why are we using `const` for `value`.

Answer (score 5):

What `const` means is that the value for that identifier *in that scope* cannot be reassigned. You can't do

```
const x = 5;
x = 6;
```

or

```
function foo(arg) {
  const theArg = arg;
  theArg = 5;
}
```

But there's nothing stopping you from running the function *again*, resulting in a new binding for that variable:

```
function foo(arg) {
  const theArg = arg;
}
foo(5);
foo(6);
```

The above is what React is doing - it runs the whole function component again, which results in `useState` returning the updated state. No `const` identifier ever gets reassigned.

Another example:

```js
let i = 0;
const useState = () => [i, newI => { i = newI; TheComponent(); }];

const TheComponent = () => {
  const [i, setI] = useState();
  console.log('component running with i of', i);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setI(i + 1);
  }, 1000);
};

TheComponent();
```